# Unable to alert before redirecting to another php script using header()

Tags: header

I was trying to create a dummy social networking site for practice. I'm stuck in a script which is sending friend request..

i've created a form(with a single text input, a hidden input and submit button) in which a logged in user can enter email address of a friend. When he clicks on the search button, he gets name and email of his friend(fetched using sql)..

With that i have added an anchor tag(named as Send request) displayed near the details. When a user clicks on the anchor tag, he is redirected to a new script which sends friend request to his friend. The second script only deals with mysql.

On sql completion, a user either gets "Friend Request Sent Successfully" alertbox or "Friend Request Already Sent"  alertbox based on sql queries. Now i want to redirect the user to the first script after the execution of alertbox.

I tried to use header("Location: send_request.php") after the alertbox. But now it is redirecting user to the first script without showing alertbox.

Here is my first script(named as find_friends.php)

```
<?php

    if(isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    require('header.php');
    echo "<form method='POST' action=''>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='search_user'/>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='search_form_status' value='sent'/>";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Search User'/>";
    echo "</form>";


    if(isset($_POST['search_form_status']) && $_POST['search_form_status']=='sent'){
        $search_user = $_POST['search_user'];
        $sql_search_user = "SELECT id, name, email FROM registration where email=\"$search_user\"";
        $query_search_user = mysql_query($sql_search_user);
        $user_check = mysql_num_rows($query_search_user);
        if($user_check==1){
            $results_search_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_search_user);
                echo $_SESSION['searched_id'] = $results_search_user['id'];
                echo $_SESSION['searched_name'] = $results_search_user['name']."<br/>";
                echo $_SESSION['searched_email'] = $results_search_user['email'];
                echo "</br/><a href='send_request.php'>Send Request</a>";
        }   
    }
?>
```

And here is second script(named as send_request.php)

```
<?php
    $db1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("test", $db1);
    $db2 = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", true);
    mysql_select_db("friends", $db2);
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    $searched_email = $_SESSION['searched_email'];
    $searched_id = $_SESSION['searched_id'];
    $user_name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $user_email = $_SESSION['email'];


    $sql_table_check = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'friends_".$searched_id."'";
    $table_check = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql_table_check, $db2));
    if($table_check==1){

        $sql_insert_values = "INSERT INTO friends_".$searched_id." VALUES(\"\", \"$user_name\", \"$user_email\", 0)";
        if(mysql_query($sql_insert_values)){
            echo "<script>alert('Friends Request Sent Successfully')</script>";
            header("Location: find_friends.php");
        }
        else{
            echo "<script>alert('Friends Request Already Sent')</script>";
            header("Location: find_friends.php");
        }       

    }else{

        $sql_create_table = "CREATE TABLE friends_".$searched_id." (friend_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, friend_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, friend_email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, active TINYINT NOT NULL)";

        $sql_insert_values = "INSERT INTO friends_".$searched_id." VALUES(\"\", \"$user_name\", \"$user_email\", 0)";

        mysql_query($sql_create_table, $db2);
        if(mysql_query($sql_insert_values, $db2)){
            echo "<script>alert('Friends Request Sent Successfully')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
 if(mysql_query($sql_insert_values)){
        echo "<script>
                   alert('Friends Request Sent Successfully');
                   window.location.href='find_friends.php';
             </script>";
    }
```